# modify shopify button code to remove photo

Tags: shopify

I need to remove the photo preview on the shopify add to cart button. When I select "button only" then the prices don't appear beside my drop boxes. When I choose "button image, price and button" option, then I get the photo, which I do not want! Is there no way to have just the add to cart button with the prices and drop down options?

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

It's good to link the code you're working with, but assuming you're using the standard snippet, adding something like:

```
.product-embed__image { 
  display: none;
}
```

Should hide it, though extra styling may be required, it'd be useful to link the page you're working on.